# Complex numbers (modulus and argument)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Find the modulus and argument of 
$ (4+2i)(-3+√2i)$ My attempt at  Solution:

Expanding, we get  $-12+4√2i+6i+2i√2i= -12+6i+4√2i+2i√2i$

I'm stuck here

Comment: Kindly ignore I made mistake of putting the i 
In the second braces inside the root.
Modulus = √220
Argument = tan^-1((3-√2))/(6+√2))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$4+2i=\sqrt{20}e^{i\tan^{-1}(1/2)},-3+\sqrt2i=\sqrt{11}e^{i\tan^{-1}(-\sqrt2/3)}$

$\therefore r=\sqrt{220},\theta=\tan^{-1}(1/2)+\tan^{-1}(-\sqrt 2/3)$.

Comment: Thanks. I made mistake of putting the i 
In the second braces inside the root.
Modulus = √220
Argument = tan^-1((3-√2))/(6+√2))